# PHP High CPU usage

Tags: mysql, php, debian, central-processing-unit

I have a dedicated server with 2 processors, 4 cores and 16GB Ram i'm hosting some php applications that uses high php and mysql usage when i check top command i find that php and mysql consume about 80% of CPU but while checking mpstat command to check usage of every core i find that all of them are 95% idle any explanation for that? note that the server becomes slow when running these applications. should i get another server with more cores?

```
top command out put:
7589 root      20   0  287648  31480  18540 R  78.7  0.2   1:49.11 php
1006 mysql     20   0 2400692 214440   6704 S  19.3  1.3 434:34.99 mysqld
18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   2.0  0.0   1435:51 ksoftirqd/2
3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   1.3  0.0   1424:58 ksoftirqd/0
5228 www-data  20   0  339616  29608  17772 S   1.3  0.2   0:00.72 apache2

mpstat -P ALL output:
root@datax:~#  mpstat -P ALL
Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 (datax)    08/15/2016      _x86_64_        (4 CPU)

04:01:58 AM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
04:01:58 AM  all    1.49    0.13    0.83    2.23    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.00   95.29
04:01:58 AM    0    1.38    0.13    0.62    2.30    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.00   95.54
04:01:58 AM    1    1.38    0.13    0.62    2.32    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.00   95.53
04:01:58 AM    2    1.62    0.13    1.04    2.15    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.00   95.03
04:01:58 AM    3    1.59    0.13    1.04    2.16    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.00   95.06
```

Comment: `top`'s most usefull information is in the header which you removed.  Put it back if you want it to be useful.  The only relevant information seen in your `mpstat` output is the `iowait` which indicates that the process running could be disk intensive.  A tool like `iostat` (part of `sysstat` package on many systems) will show you more details on that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a single instance of the code at a time, and the code is not multi-threaded, more cores won't help you.

PHP can use multiple cores with many simultaneous requests, since then there are no internal code dependencies which interfere with multi-threading.